# How to change the reveal modal speed in Foundation 5?

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation-5

I would like to change the speed at which the Reveal Modal in Foundation 5 opens and closes. I find it a bit too slow. Is there a way to do this by changing a variable or something simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it may have been a bit of a waste to post this question because the answer came to me pretty quick. You need to edit the variable `animation_speed` variable which is set to 250 ms by default. One gotcha: if you downloaded the `foundation.js` file with all the plugins together in one file, don't go and edit the `foundation.reveal.js` file but rather the other one.